# After editing pie chart title in google sheets with a function the pie chart displays an error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, pie-chart

Hello I have a problem with a pie chart in google sheets. My chart only uses one column (B)

[image: Example Data Column]

And this is how the chart should look.
[image: Pie Chart]

I am using a function in order to change the subtitle dynamically.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange("W2");
  var games = cell.getValue();
  var valuss = "Bei "+ games + " Spielen";
  //chartID: 406659648
  // Get the chart to update
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0]; // replace 0 with the index of the chart you want to update (if you have multiple charts)
  
    // Update the chart title with the new value
    chart = chart.modify().setOption('subtitle', valuss).build();
    sheet.updateChart(chart);


    var values = sheet.getRange("A1:B").getValues();

      // Update the appropriate cell with the new subtitle
      values[0][1] = newValue;

      // Set the updated values back to the range
      sheet.getRange("A1:B").setValues(values);
  
  chart = chart.modify().setOption('options', options).build();
    
    sheet.withSuccessHandler(function(){
        SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Force the changes to be applied immediately
      }).getCharts();
}
```

But after this code gets executed my pie chart displays the following
[image: Pie Chart error]

which is German for "At least 2 columns required, but only 1 available"

If I now I click the "Aggregate" checkbox the chart looks perfectly fine and the subtitle is correctly edited.

Does anyone know why that is ?

Best Regards,
Lukas